# windows phone App submit test fail

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, http-headers, windows-phone, webclient, windows-phone-store

I am working on **windows phone 8.1 silverlight** App. I need to implement `Accept-Encoding` header with `gZip` for both `HTTP and HTTPS` protocol.

I implement with `WebClient` but with `HTTP` API request get response like ������ this is happens with only `HTTP` request, It's working fine with `HTTPS`.

My main concern is App need to run on both `HTTP and HTTPS` protocol.

I do some google and get some near about solution so include **SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.1.4.0.0** from NuGet, and implement `Accept-Encoding` header with `gZip` for both `HTTP and HTTPS` protocol and app working fine in `Debug and Release` mode while I directly deploy from Visual Studio to my windows phone.

But problem raised when I upload release mode app on windows phone store I getting this error from store [image: Get error from store when app publish]

I don't know why message say in **SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll is built in debug mode** because upload app on store in release mode.

Comment: It says, you have added SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll  in your project and it is build on the release mode.  Build the  SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll on release mode & add it again to the solution

Comment: @asitis You mean to say remove SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll and rebulid solution in release mode then add SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll again in solution.. Right ?

Comment: yes. you have to do the same.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Also post answer if it's good then do some action on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution Download [SharpGIS.GZipWebClient](https://github.com/dotMorten/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient) from this link.

First of all open downloaded project in **Visual Studio** and Rebuild in `Release mode with ARM` pick `SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll` from **SharpGIS.GZipWebClient** project `Bin-->ARM-->Release`

Put `SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll` in windows phone app

`packages-->SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.x.x.x.x-->lib-->wp71` then add as references from `packages` folder in windows phone project.

This is definitely work because it's works for me.

**Note:** SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.x.x.x.x where x.x.x.x is version of SharpGIS.GZipWebClient

Answer (score 1):

1. Rebuild your `SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll` library in **`Release mode`**.
2. Add SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.dll to your solution & refer it.
3. Build you solution in Release mode
4. Upload .xap file to the store.

   Then your issue will be resolved.